# Why does my thirdweb cli doesnt accept thirdweb command?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, thirdweb

Hello guys im a new student working on a toturial. So i have installed thirdweb but the thirdweb command for the cli doesnt seem to be working. When i try npx thirdweb it seems to be working but its not the cli. If someone could help it would be amazing cuz im in a bit of a hurry. Thank you!

I tried subbmitting a ticket and requesting help from their discord but they havent awensered